# How to know if a GameObject has a mesh in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attached the following script to a GameObject to determine if it is a mesh.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var meshChecker = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        if(meshChecker != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("this is mesh");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("this is not mesh");
        }
    }
}
```

This script seems to work fine as far as I've tried.

However, this method does not seem to be able to determine all meshes.

For example, there is a mesh with a blendShapeds.I opened and looked at the Inspector for that mesh. It seemed that the the mesh have "SkinMeshRenderer" and the  mesh didn't have "MeshRenderer". And the above script output "this is not mesh".

The solution to this problem is to modify the script as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var meshChecker = this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        var blendShapeChecker = this.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        if (meshChecker != null || blendShapeChecker != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("this is mesh");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("this is not mesh");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if the second script solves all the problems.
If anyone knows how to accurately determine all meshes, please let me know.

Comment: Please don't tag with unrelated language tags. There is no C code but seems to be C#.

Comment: I tagged it in C #, but strangely it was converted to C. I think this is not my problem but a Stackoverflow bug. If you look at the edit history in the past, you can see that the change hasn't been applied even though I updated it twice in an attempt to fix the tag.

Comment: That is probably because it is C# and not C #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Mesh Filter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshFilter.html) to avoid having all the controls via code.

In this way instead of having

```
if (meshChecker != null || blendShapeChecker != null || othermeshes...)
```

You will check

```
if(MeshFilter.mesh != null)
```

But with the Mesh Filter you can play with multiple meshes and check between all of them with the [Mesh.SubMeshCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-subMeshCount.html) or the [Mesh.setIndices](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetIndices.html) or even [Mesh.CombineMeshes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html) but it's all about the usage you need for the game!